# Git clone hangs in vitual machine

Tags: git

Please, help someone.

> /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/someproject/Project.git
> /var/folders/nc/fk4zxcg13w99jjkjfcv_1p3h0000gn/T/d20160909-5467-gcadxt
> --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.0.0 --verbose

always hangs:

> Cloning into
> '/var/folders/nc/fk4zxcg13w99jjkjfcv_1p3h0000gn/T/d20160909-5467-gcadxt'...
>
> POST git-upload-pack (155 bytes)
>
> POST git-upload-pack (164 bytes)
>
> remote: Counting objects: 220, done.
>
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (191/191), done.
>
> Receiving objects:  50% (112/220), 7.39 MiB | 1.83 MiB/s   s

Why this appears? The same machine cloned in to another laptop. It works correctly. But in the first one - no. What do I have  to update?

Comment: i'm no expert but isn't that a weirdly named directory to put anything in ? what if you just go into a regular directory like `cd $home`  `mkdir abc`  `cd abc` then run `git clone https://github.com/someproject/Project.git` from there